# Find and replace a part of several lines in multiple documents using python?

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm trying to replace parts of several lines in multiple latex documents using python. This is what I've done:

```
import fileinput, glob, string, sys, os
from os.path import join

def search_rep(path,search,replace):


# replace a string in multiple files


    files = glob.glob(path)

    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            for line in file.splitlines(): # or whatever arbitrary loop
                if line.find(search) > -1:
                    print "Replacing" + replace + "on line: %s" % line
                    line.replace(search, replace)



def main():

    path = "/home/stig/test/*.tex"
    search = "/home/stig/hfag/oppgave/figs_plots/"
    replace = "/home/stig/forskning_linux/oppgave_hf2/figs_plots/"
    search_rep(path,search,replace)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

But the script doesn't change anything in the files. What's wrong?

Thanks

Stig

Comment: you have to write files back, now you just changing lines in memory

Comment: did you know anythins about regular expression ?

[link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: You aren't even opening the files, you are searching only in their names.

Comment: I know this may not be what you're looking for, but since you're on *nix have you considered just using the tools BASH gives you?  This is a one-line operation with `ls | sed`

Comment: @roippi, Indeed. You don't even need `ls`, `sed -i 's/$search/$replace/' $path` would work. Then again, excluding the imports my answer only has two lines, and can be readily extended in python.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html). It's a good fit for this problem. [Example](http://effbot.org/librarybook/fileinput.htm):

```
import fileinput
import glob
import sys

path = "/home/stig/test/*.tex"
search = "/home/stig/hfag/oppgave/figs_plots/"
replace = "/home/stig/forskning_linux/oppgave_hf2/figs_plots/"

for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob(path), inplace=1):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace(search, replace))
```

See also the `inplace` and `backup` parameters, which allow you to do the replacement in place (with the safety of backup in case of a mistake).

Comment: Use `inplace=1` in `fileinput.input` to write the files back in-place.

Comment: Thanks! I get the right output with: 

   for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob(path), inplace = 1):
        if fileinput.isfirstline(): 
            sys.stderr.write("-- reading %s --\n" % fileinput.filename())
       string.upper(line))
        
        if line.find(search) > -1:
            line = line.replace(search, replace)
            print line                                             ,but it's written on the first line in the document and wiping out the rest of the text. What do you guys suggest?

Comment: You're welcome. But the code was just an example, you can remove the part that checks whether it's the first line (in fact, you should, otherwise you'll have that extraneous line in all your files). And you should probably use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`. Aren't you getting extra newlines in the files?

Comment: @user2022266, edited answer to fit your case, let me know if it doesn't work.